# Validações com Laravel - Input e Option

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho um formulário que recebo um endereço de email e qual o tipo de email. O Preenchimento dos campos não devem ser obrigatórios. Caso seja preenchido o email preciso que seja fornecido o tipo.

Segue exemplo:

- Email - Opcional
- Tipo de Email - Opcional

  ---
- Email - Caso Preenchido
- Tipo de Email - Obrigatório.

Segue formulário que estou utilizando:

```html
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <div class="input-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" value="" id="email" name="email"
              placeholder="Email">

          <select class="form-control select2" name="tipo_email" style="width: 100%;">
              <option value="" selected="">Selecione</option>
              <option value="1">Pessoal</option>
              <option value="2">Corporativo</option>
          </select>
      </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Tentei utilizar a validação do Laravel **required_unless** mas não consegui. Alguém consegue me ajudar ?

Comment: mano bom dia, você usar o Rule::requiredIf https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-required-if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde man, o melhor maneira de se validar séria com o [Rule::Requiredif](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-required-if), ele é da classe Rule do laravel para validação na parte do cliente.

```
//Não esquece os namespaces
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

Ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
$validator  = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'tipo_email' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) { //Se o email estiver preenchido o campo tipo_email passa a ser obrigatório.
                return $request->get('email') !== null ? true : false; //Verifica se o email foi preenchido
            }),
        ]);
```

Capturando as mensagem de erros e redirecionando para exibir:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
     return redirect('home')
       ->withErrors($validator)
       ->withInput();
}
```

Rota post para o cadastro:

```
Route::post('/cadastro/pessoa', 'UserController@cadastroPessoa')->name('cadastro.pessoa');
```

No seu formulário ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
             <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                   <li>{{ $error }}</li>
               @endforeach
           </ul>
        </div>
    @endif

   <div style="display:flex;justify-content: center;">
     <form action="{{ route('cadastro.pessoa') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <div class="input-group">
           <input type="email" class="form-control" value="" id="email" name="email"placeholder="Email">

          <select class="form-control select2" id="tipo_email" name="tipo_email" style="width: 100%;">
             <option value="" selected="">Selecione</option>
             <option value="1">Pessoal</option>
             <option value="2">Corporativo</option>
         </select>
       </div>
     </div>
        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
   </form>
 </div>
```